# jQuery for function display data with different array value row

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery function

```
var chkLength = jsonStr.item1.length; //count data item1
var chkLength2 = jsonStr.item2.length; //count data item2

for(var i = 0; i < chkLength; i++)
{
    var copy = "<li><a class='item1Name'><div class='titleItem1Name'>" + jsonStr.item1[i] + "</div><div class='quantity'><div class='minQuantity'>Min. Qty <div class='minQuantityItem1Name'>" + jsonStr.minQtyItem1[i] + "</div></div><div class='stock'>Stock <div>0</div></div></div></a>" 
    + 
    "<ul><li><a class='item2Name'><div class='titleItem2Name'>" + jsonStr.item2[i] + "</div><div class='quantity'><div class='minQuantity'>Min. Qty <div class='minQuantityItem2Name'>" + jsonStr.minQtyItem2[i] + "</div></div><div class='stock'>Stock <div>0</div></div></div></a></ul></li></ul></li>";

    $("#item1Name").append(copy);
}
```

chkLength have 2 data, chkLength2 have 6 data.

When I run the code, it only show 2 data for chkLength2. I think it's because chkLength only have 2 data then it show item2 only 2.

I'm display it to hierarcy chart below:
[image]

Is there any way to do it?

[image]

Comment: That's because you're looping `chkLength` only. If you want to show all entities from both arrays you need two loops, or to at least iterate over the longer one and fail gracefully if one is shorter than the other

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan I set the data into hierarcy chart(you can see my updated question above). If 2 loops is it possible to display the data correctly in hierarcy chart?

Comment: Any clue Sir? :)

Comment: @HiDayurieDave your question is little vague. do try making a readymade code using any fiddle

Comment: Hi @vibs2006 The point is, as you can see above image Incoming Details, based on my data from database it should be show 6 data not 2 data. PS-900, FX-888D, FX-951, 937, 942, 990